# Disable Whole Redactor.js WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: jquery, redactor, redactor.js

Like you can disable a `<textarea disabled>...</textarea>` component, I would like to disable a redactor editor, but still display it on my page.

I would expect Redactor to read the disabled attribute on the textarea I am initializing, and disable the editor as appropriate, but it does not work and creates a fully functional editor instead.

```
<textarea class="redactor" disabled></textarea>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('.redactor').redactor();
});
</script>
```

Is there an additional API command or workaround I can use to create a disabled editor?  An easy way to disable and enable it would be preferred.  I can't seem to find anything in the Redactor documentation or API on how to do it.

I'm using Redactor 9.1.9, but am willing to upgrade if necessary.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable the editor, please try to set the `contenteditable` attribute to `false`. If you check the source code in  the browser (with Firebug for example), you will see that the div which wraps the editor has the `contenteditable="true`" attribute. So try to change this with jQuery for example:

> $('.redactor-editor').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

or Angular (in my case):

> angular.element('.redactor-editor').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

You can try to do this with a `timeout` in order to make sure the content from the editor is fully generated and you have access to its attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem where I needed to enable/disable Redactor in certain situations. Ended up going with something like this: http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/click-to-edit/

In that example, clicking the textarea 'enables' Redactor by loading it and clicking save 'disables' by destroying it.

With your example, `$(".redactor").redactor('destroy')` would remove the Redactor bells and whistles and leave you with a disabled textarea. `$(".redactor").redactor()` would enable it again.

Not sure if it's the best solution but like you mentioned, their API doesn't appear to have a different way to do it.

Comment: A disabled text area would show the HTML inside of the redactor, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: FYI, seems like the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

To disable:

```
element.redactor('core.editor').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
```

To enable

```
element.redactor('core.editor').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
```